# Cannot connect to neo4j running in droplet but using lynx to navigate to localhost:7474 works, ufw & digital ocean firewall configured

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neo4j, digital-ocean, droplet

I'm running a brand new droplet in digital ocean running on `Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64`, neo4j status is active and remote interface available on port 7474.

- Using lynx via ssh to browse to localhost:7474 works, neo4j is alive and active.
- Pinging works
- Firewall asigned to allow all traffic but also specifically those ports
- Browsing to the ip address on any port does not work
- Used ufw to manually add port 80, 443, 7474 to allow access
- Cannot connect via browser to the droplet on any port

Firewall configuration:

[image]

UFW Status:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure the following line in your `neo4j.conf` file is uncommented :

```
# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Hi -- forgot to mention this, I have indeed done this to my neo4j.conf file before posting here, as I have seen that mentioned on another forum, didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem to use this command. If you had been created container using 7474 and 7687 ports you will have an error "port is already allocated". So yo should delete this container.

Command :

```
docker run --name neo4j -p7474:7474 -p7687:7687 -d -v $HOME/neo4j/data:/data -v $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs -v $HOME/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import -v $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins neo4j:latest
```